# Optimization levels with tiny C compiler

Tags: tcc

I've read in the manpage that

> Note: GCC options -Ox, -fx and -mx are ignored.

It produces different binary sizes, compiling st with `gcc -O3`, the binary size is 120K and with tcc it's 112K.

Is code compiled with tcc running slower than `gcc -O3`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tcc does not optimise. Normally, gcc's optimisations result in binaries which run considerably faster. (The size of the binary is not a predictor of execution speed, by the way.)

Comment: Are there any other fast, small c compilers that have the option to optimise?

Comment: @paul: Probably not. Optimisation is a big complicated problem. A compiler is either small and fast and produces unoptimised code, or it's big and slow, and produces better code.